# Error with code for playlists in java mp3 player

Tags: java, mp3, playlist

I'm struggling with creating a playlist for my simple mp3 player in Java but the code is somehow not working. Here is the playlist part:

```
FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("MP3 Files", "mp3", "mpeg3");
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("C:\\Users\\Junior\\Music");
chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    //File myFile=chooser.getSelectedFile();
    File[] files=chooser.getSelectedFiles();
    //String song=myFile+"";
    for(int i=0; i<files.length;i++){
    name=files[i].getName()+"";//getting song name for display purpose
    try {
        MC.Stop();//stopping if any file is playing

        display.setText(name.substring(0,name.length()-4));//setting name songs in display (without .mp3)


        MC.Play(files[i]+"");//from main class i'm calling play method
    } catch (IOException e) {//i'm not really catching any exceptions so...

    }//end of catch
    }//end of for-loop
}//end of if
```

This code is playing the last song selected (even if I choose multiple files - so the last selected song) but not advancing to the next song.

Comment: The reason you are hearing the last song is because it plays the other songs and stops them as fast as the for loop can find the file. Looks like you might need a way of waiting for the song to end before playing the next song.

Comment: Ohh I didn't see that. Thanks! But do you maybe know some more of how to creating a playlist?

Answer (score 1):

I thought this might help you from reading your comment. This is a playlist class that I created. It's an abstract class, so you need to create your own class that extends this class, and implement the `loadSongs` method

```
public abstract class Playlist {

    public static final int LOOP_NONE = 0;
    public static final int LOOP_PLAYLIST = 1;
    public static final int LOOP_SONG = 2;

    private List<File> songs;
    private int playlistPos;
    private int loopMode;
    private boolean isShuffled;


    public Playlist() {
        isShuffled = false;
        loopMode = 0;
    }


    protected abstract List<File> loadPlaylist();


    public void initPlaylist() {
        songs = loadPlaylist();
    }


    public File getCurrentSong() {
        return songs.get(playlistPos);
    }


    public int getPlaylistPosition() {
        return playlistPos;
    }


    public void setPlaylistPosition(int playlistPos) {
        this.playlistPos = playlistPos;
    }


    public int getPlaylistSize() {
        return songs.size();
    }


    public boolean isFinalSong() {
        return playlistPos == songs.size() - 1;
    }


    public boolean isShuffled() {
        return isShuffled;
    }


    public int getLoopMode() {
        return loopMode;
    }


    public void toggleShuffle() {
        setShuffle(!isShuffled);
    }


    public void toggleLoop() {
        loopMode = (loopMode + 1) % 3;
    }


    public void skipForward() {
        playlistPos = (playlistPos + 1) % songs.size();
        // Re-shuffle songs each time the playlist loops
        if (playlistPos == 0 && isShuffled) {
            shuffle();
        }
    }


    public void skipBack() {
        playlistPos = playlistPos == 0 ? songs.size() - 1 : playlistPos - 1;
    }


    public void setLoop(int loopMode) {
        this.loopMode = loopMode;
    }


    public void setShuffle(boolean shuffle) {
        this.isShuffled = shuffle;
        if (isShuffled) {
            shuffle();
        }
        else {
            unshuffle();
        }
    }


    protected void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(songs.subList(playlistPos + 1, songs.size()));
    }


    protected void unshuffle() {
        initPlaylist();
    }

}
```

So you would create a subclass like this:

```
public TestPlaylist extends Playlist {

    @Override
    protected List<File> loadPlaylist() {
        // Show your file chooser, and return the selected files
        // as a list.
    }
}
```

And to use it, you would write:

```
Playlist playlist = new TestPlaylist();
playlist.initPlaylist();

// Do what you want with it, for example:
playlist.setShuffle(true);
MC.play(playlist.getCurrentSong().getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much! I created a new class where I wrote first part of the code then I created subclass (new class) TestPlayList with second part of the code but when I did this it gives me an error: type List does not take parameters. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You need to import `java.util.List`, not `java.awt.List`

Comment: it worked! just (and really) just one more thing... you said that I must return selected files as a list. I get files with `File[] files=chooser.getSelectedFiles();` and then i return `files;`. But it gives me and error that `File[] cannot be converted to List<File>`. Why is that? And I really apreciate your help man, love you!

Comment: Haha, no worries. That's because File[] is an array, but we need a List. So, you should try `return Arrays.toList(files);`

Comment: Heya it didn't give me an error this time, but it doesn't work as it should. If I choose multiple files it plays me just first selected song and thats it. I did everything as you said but still not working. Must I manually change that when the song is finished it will play the next one on the list? And yes sorry that I'm so dumb but I have java second year now and I don't know much.

Comment: Yes, you need to call `playlist.skipForward();` when the song has finished. Usually, you would set some kind of listener on the media player that you're using. Which class do you use to play the files?

Comment: I use `FileInputStream` and `BufferedInputStream`. So let's say `if((FIS.available)==0){playlist.skipForward();}` ? Something like that?